# Why applied CILinearGradient to CIMaskedVariableBlur shrinks image of UIImageView?

Tags: swift, uikit, cifilter

I'm tring example code of Apple's [Selectively Focusing on an Image](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreimage/selectively_focusing_on_an_image) article. However image of UIImageView is shrinked after filter applied. I can not figure out where is the problem. Needs your help.

## Here is my code:

```
        self.view.addSubview(imageView)
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        imageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        imageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        imageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 270).isActive = true
        imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 480).isActive = true
        
        if let uiImage = UIImage(named: "Image"), let ciImage = CIImage(image: uiImage) {
            let h = ciImage.extent.size.height
            guard let topGradient = CIFilter(name:"CILinearGradient") else {
                return
            }
            topGradient.setValue(CIVector(x:0, y:0.85 * h),
                                 forKey:"inputPoint0")
            topGradient.setValue(CIColor.green,
                                 forKey:"inputColor0")
            topGradient.setValue(CIVector(x:0, y:0.6 * h),
                                 forKey:"inputPoint1")
            topGradient.setValue(CIColor(red:0, green:1, blue:0, alpha:0),
                                 forKey:"inputColor1")
            
            guard let bottomGradient = CIFilter(name:"CILinearGradient") else {
                return
            }
            bottomGradient.setValue(CIVector(x:0, y:0.35 * h),
                                    forKey:"inputPoint0")
            bottomGradient.setValue(CIColor.green,
                                    forKey:"inputColor0")
            bottomGradient.setValue(CIVector(x:0, y:0.6 * h),
                                    forKey:"inputPoint1")
            bottomGradient.setValue(CIColor(red:0, green:1, blue:0, alpha:0),
                                    forKey:"inputColor1")
            
            guard let gradientMask = CIFilter(name:"CIAdditionCompositing") else {
                return
            }
            gradientMask.setValue(topGradient.outputImage,
                                  forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
            gradientMask.setValue(bottomGradient.outputImage,
                                  forKey: kCIInputBackgroundImageKey)
            
            guard let maskedVariableBlur = CIFilter(name:"CIMaskedVariableBlur") else {
                return
            }
            maskedVariableBlur.setValue(ciImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
            maskedVariableBlur.setValue(gradientMask.outputImage, forKey: "inputMask")
            if let selectivelyFocusedCIImage = maskedVariableBlur.outputImage {
                imageView.image = UIImage(ciImage: selectivelyFocusedCIImage)
            }
            
        }
```

## Result:

[image]

I'm tring to apply CIMaskedVariableBlur fiter to my UIImageView however image of UIImageView is shrinked unexpectedly.

Answer (score 1):

It's not really "shrinking" the image... in fact, it's **growing** the image. Because you have your image view's contentMode set to `.scaleAspectFill` you're not seeing the actual output `UIImage`.

Aside from that, things can get confusing anyway...

When using `CIFilter` and translating between `UIImage` and `CIImage` (and/or `CGImage`) we have to take the `.extent` rect into account.

Rather than trying to precisely explain that (in part because I'm not entirely clear on it to begin with), here's how you can get back what you're expecting from that (Apple's example) code.

If you change the very last "conversion" part from:

```
if let selectivelyFocusedCIImage = maskedVariableBlur.outputImage {
    imageView.image = UIImage(ciImage: selectivelyFocusedCIImage)
}
```

to:

```
if let selectivelyFocusedCIImage = maskedVariableBlur.outputImage {
    let context = CIContext()
    if let cgimg = context.createCGImage(selectivelyFocusedCIImage, from: ciImage.extent) {
        imageView.image = UIImage(cgImage: cgimg)
    }
}
```

you should get the expected result.

Comment: Thank you for your rerply, I found same code in SO however, still don't know the logic behind.